# Can I access Image Suite in a JavaScript workflow?

Tags: automator, javascript-automation

I want to write a simple Automator action to scale an image to an an arbitrary percentage. Using the standard Automator actions, I don’t think that’s possible - I need to set the size in the action itself.

My thought is that by adding a **Run JavaScript** action, I should be able to ask for the percentage and scale the image that way. I’m using JavaScript because I know it well, and feel more at home with it than working with AppleScript.

In the Script Editor, the library includes **Image Events**, which appears to have a `scale` method.

Is it possible to access this library from JavaScript in Automator? How would I do that?

I’m on MacOS Big Sur.

Comment: The question is what you mean by “using JavaScript”. You can write automation scripts on macOS in a flavour of JS known as _JavaScript for Automation_, but you cannot access scripting extensions in a script that runs outside the automation runtime system (which also hosts AppleScript).

Comment: @kopischke I mean _JavaScript for Automation_. I’ve edited the text and added another tag for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

… and the answer is **yes**:

```js
var imageEvents = Application('Image Events');
var path = '…';
var img = imageEvents.open(path);
img.scale({byFactor: 50/100});
img.save();
```

It’s just a matter of knowing about the `Application()` function and interpreting the information in the Library info in Script Editor.